# How to calculate run time memory and maximum data memory usage in following c program

Tags: c++, c, stack, memory-layout

**Here is my code**

run time memory will depend on the OS but i don't want that level.just want to solve this type question from basic level.

```
include <studio.h>

int calculate(int n);

int number = 8;

  int main(){

  int add;

  add = calculate(number);

  return 0;

}

int calculate(int x){

  if(x==0){

    return x;

  }else{

    return x+calculate(x-1);

  }

}
```

Comment: Use `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `include <studio.h>`

Comment: 'run time memory will depend on the OS' yes, exactly.  Your little program ios so simple that the code, data, stack etc. segments will be the initial working set as supplied by the OS loader and virtual memory manager.  You can get some idea of how much memory your program requires by examining the linker map file.

Answer (score 0):

First problem, Use

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

instead of

```
include <studio.h>
```

Second problem, use `x` instead of `n`,

```
return x+calculate(x-1);
```

**Full code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculate(int n);

int number = 8;

int main()
{
        int add;

        add = calculate(number);
        printf("%d\n", add);
        return 0;
}

int calculate(int x)
{
        int n = 0;
        if(x==0)
        {
                return x;
        }
        else
        {
                return x+calculate(x-1);
        }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?